# find_or_create_by Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How should I write `find_or_create_by` method to create or find `Clicks` by the field `clicktime`, so clicks that was created within 24 hours were unique? 


***Create method:***

```
description = Description.find(params[:id])
click = description.clicks
        .find_or_create_by(clicktime: ___ )
Click.increment_counter(:count, click.id)
```

***Show method:***

```
@descriptions = Description.includes(:clicks)
.where(:clicks => { clicktime: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now })
.order('count DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find_or_create you can use first_or_create

```
click = description.clicks.where(clicktime: ___ ).first_or_create
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I wanted to pass time range, like: `(Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now` that was my problem cause even if it could check whether such record exist, method don`t know what to write if it is not exist. I already posted my implementation for this case.
But thank you for answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
description = Description.find(params[:id])
click = description.clicks.
         find_by(clicktime: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now)

if click != nil
  Click.increment_counter(:count, click.id)
else
  new_click = description.clicks.create(clicktime: Time.now)
  Click.increment_counter(:count, new_click.id)
end
```

Comment: Found decision by my own. Just check first if such record exist and then update it or create new one. Worked without `find_or_create_by`.